# How to combine two Python script

Tags: python, twitter

Hi i'm a newbie to Python and i'm just a learner, recently i tried to combine two scripts (retweet and tweet) into one with a interval between two but unfortunately it always ends with an error, i don't know how to solve this error.

**Here is my code:**

```
# importing the module 
import tweepy
from time import sleep
import random

# personal information 
api_key = "xxxx"
api_secret_key = "yyyy"
access_token = "xxxx"
access_token_secret ="yyyy"


# authentication 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key) 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret) 


# authentication of access token and secret 
api = tweepy.API(auth) 


#put your tweets here
#some of these tweets have been taken from the top section of the hashtag #BoycottPexa,credit goes to the respective users 
list=["t.co/DVIh9Pqtu",
"t.co/mkPzaqXge",
"t.co/ql9UxICTy",
"t.co/dDSkDij92",
"t.co/LeTY4JRQP"
]


# Retweet and Favorite the tweet
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = ("#twitter -filter:retweets"),lang="en").items(): 
    try: 
        print("\nTweet by: @" + tweet.user.screen_name) 

        tweet.retweet() 
        print("Retweeted the tweet") 

            tweet.favorite() 
            print("Favorited the tweet") 
            sleep(360)

# Posting of tweets 
for i in range(len(list)):
    try:
        #insert more hashtags if you want to here
        string = f"{random.randint(0,99)}"
        api.update_status(status =string+" "+" #Twitter"+" "+ list[i])
        print("successfully tweeted")
        sleep(360)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Error i received:

```
    File "post.py", line 95
2020-07-26T07:45:45.598784+00:00 app[worker.1]: tweet.favorite() 
2020-07-26T07:45:45.598785+00:00 app[worker.1]: ^
2020-07-26T07:45:45.598786+00:00 app[worker.1]: IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance .

Comment: What error are you getting? Including full error message would go along way in helping people figure out what's happening.

Comment: Updated brother .

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error says: you have indentation problem in your code.

It appears that it is happening here:

```py
        tweet.retweet() 
        print("Retweeted the tweet") 
            
            # This bit has no reason to be indented
            tweet.favorite() 
            print("Favorited the tweet") 
            sleep(360)
```

Comment: Thanks i fixed the intended error but now I received "syntax error"  2020-07-26T08:38:39.605160+00:00 app[worker.1]: sleep(60)
2020-07-26T08:38:39.605160+00:00 app[worker.1]: ^
2020-07-26T08:38:39.605165+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: @kannankr, the error message says you have an error in line `sleep(60)` , but I don't see it in the code you provided.